# 3D Plotting with (or without) mesh in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

I have a function `G(a,b)` that takes two inputs and returns a number. The function itself involves using ode45 and eigenvalues of some matrix depending on the values of a and b.  I want to look at a 3D plot (ideally a 2D heat plot of `G` vs `a` and `b`, but I know MATLAB can twist axes and stuff).

I have tried 2 approaches. The first is the nested for loops

```
i=1
j=1
for a = 0:1:40 ;
   for b = 0:.1:10 ;
      Value(i,j) = G(a,b);
      B(j)=b;
      j=j+1 ;
    end
    A(i) = a;
    i=i+1 ;
end
```

Why I do not like this:  I end up with three vectors/arrays: `A` `B` and `G`.  Since `G` is 2D, I cannot just do `surf(A,B,G)`.  So my next thought was mesh:

```
a = 0:1:40;
b = 0:.1:10;
[A,B] = meshgrid(a,b);
Value = G(A,B);
```

Now my error is understandably that my function wants numbers `a`,`b` not arrays.

So I am kind of stuck as to how to best approach this and any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions come to my mind. **First**, implement `G` function using `.` operators. For example, if there is any `a*b`, change it to `a.*b`, or `a/b` change it to `a./b`.

**Second**, if your function can be implemented in a symbolic format, you can plot your function using `ezmesh` in a simple format.

In sum, the solution to your question depends on implementation of `G` function.